# how to make expect script wait till the shell script is finished

Tags: wait, expect

I have written an expect script which automatically switches from normal user to oracle user and fires a script which is used for taking database backup.
Now the problem is i want expect script to wait till the other shell script gets executed ie till the database backup has been taken successfully.
I have tried googling and found somethings:
1) use wait in expect script. but i cannot find how to use the wait command in expect script to wait till the other script gets executed.
2) use system command in expect script to call the other shell script, but i cannot find the exact syntax of how to use it. also this seems to be a c programming command(if so then i cannot use it).

please suggest some ways to make expect script wait till the child process is finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In expect, you would do something like

```
set timeout -1
send "su - oracle\r"
expect $oracle_shell_prompt
send "backup_script.sh\r"
expect $oracle_shell_prompt
puts "backup script done"
send "exit\r"
expect $normal_user_prompt
```

Comment: my $oracle_shell_prompt is something like this [oracle@inauto04 ~]$ where the part after @ will change depending on the machine on which db is taken. how should i use regular expression for this???

Comment: `set oracle_shell_prompt {\]\$ ?$}` and `expect -re $oracle_shell_prompt`

Comment: `$normal_user_prompt` is an environment variable or where are those coming from?

Comment: It's an expect variable that you define.